# Errors followed by command "Sudo nautilus"

Tags: command-line, nautilus, sudo

I have opened `Nautilus` with root power to delete some items.When I typed `Sudo nautilus`,the particular window opened up,but some errors also came along with it as following:

```
meego@meego-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo nautilus
[sudo] password for meego: 
Initializing nautilus-gdu extension

** (nautilus:5579): WARNING **: Failed to get the current CK session: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.GeneralError: Unable to lookup session information for process '5579'

(nautilus:5579): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.


** (nautilus:5579): WARNING **: Could not inhibit power management: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Name "org.gnome.SessionManager" does not exist

** (nautilus:5579): WARNING **: Could not inhibit power management: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Name "org.gnome.SessionManager" does not exist
```

What all these means?

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to bother with this things. These are not errors but warnings. It is probably for the reason that, the `root` user has no session currently, and you are not logged in as `root`. so ignore these messages.

You can get rid of these kind of messages (*if you want*) by running `gksu nautilus` command in the run command window. Pressing `alt+f2` will bring up one.

#### The terminal way

you can open nautilus with root access in terminal without error messages by typing this
`sudo -i nautilus &> /dev/null`.  Here the error messages are redirected to another output device, which is simply null or nothing. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/150846/61218) for more

Comment: .Thanx for the answer.

Comment: If this answer helped you, Consider accepting this by clicking on the grey tick mar at the left hand side of the answer