# How to really hide terminal output?

Tags: command-line

I know that to launch an application and still keep working on the terminal, `&` is put in the end of command (like `emacs&`)
But some commands still keep printing on the terminal, like this

[image]

So how to really keep the command *quiet* on the terminal?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you are seeing are the errors, being printed to stderr (standard error). By default stderr is printed to the terminal used to start the program. We can change this easily though, to point to `/dev/null`, which is basically a black hole. It's a device that doesn't do anything, so when you write to it, nothing actually happens. The following command will redirect ALL output (stderr and stdout) to `/dev/null` and then give you back your terminal.

```
firefox &> /dev/null &
```

The `&>` is the redirector, `/dev/null` is where we are redirecting to, and the last `&` means to "background" the process, so we can have our terminal back.

On a side note, if you ever want to bring a backgrounded program back to the terminal, you can use the `fg` (short for foreground) command to bring it back. And if you type the combination of keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> you will be able to "suspend" the process, then you can type `bg` to send it back to background.

Comment: Good Explanation ..........